# how i can change type of dhtmxlgantt calendar to jalali?

Tags: calendar, persian

I need to use Jalali (Persian) date type on [dhtmlxGantt](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/index.shtml)
and I changed some methods on the source file, so when I'm using scale time to month or year it doesn't work.

[image]

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yahmat/dhtmlxgantt
with this confg:

```
gantt.i18n.setLocale("fa");
gantt.config.jalali = true;
gantt.config.rtl = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali you can use Jalali date for your app.